# Angular2 add component in a dynamic way

Tags: angular, dynamic, typescript

actually i'm trying to find a workaround for import and resolve a component i a dynamic way, I used to use System.import and then componentResolver for accomplish it(RC4), then when i migrated the project to the final version of angular that way is not allowed anymore, because System.import is not able to resolve the path of the component if it is on a variable(the path is and needs to be in a variable), according with my research is a problem of the context, but i have no idea how to fix it

The following code used to work

```
System.import(formPath).then((module: any) => {
    this.widgetService.add(new Widget('Widgets.Form',
                                       module[Object.keys(module)[0]],
                                       1
                                       )
                          );
    },
    (err: any) => console.error(err)
)
```

but now i can't do that, i'm trying the following code

```
System.import(pathToForm)
    .then(cmp => console.log(cmp))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Someone have any idea of how to do make it work?

By the way, i'm using angular-cli which use webpack

I also tested with require and i have the same behavior.

Thanks in advance, and sorry by my english.

**Edit:**
I found why System.import was not working for me, i totally forgot that i migrated from systemJS to angular-cli(which use webpack) however there should be a way to make a require from a variable, as i use to do it with SystemJS

Answer (score 0):

`System.import` was not working for me, I totally forgot that I migrated from systemJS to angular-cli(which use webpack) however there should be a way to make a require from a variable, as I use to do it with SystemJS